# Streaming audio recording from browser to server?

Tags: python, audio, browser, streaming, audio-recording

I've found things that let you record audio in a browser and *then* save it to a server. Is there anything out there that lets you do streaming recording -- that is, sending the audio in chunks to a server rather than waiting until after the entire recording has been done?

I'm wondering this because I'd like to record a long-ish (15-20 min) length audio recording and I want to avoid the risk of something going wrong after the recording, or facing an audio file that is too large to easily upload.

On the client/browser end ideally we're talking Flash (obviously as soon as there is any kind of support in HTML5 we'll switch to that) and then on the server end pretty much anything that will run on a Linux box, although something in Python would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

[`getUserMedia`](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html) allows this and live streaming to the server. However, support is sparse, and you'll need a [wrapper](https://gist.github.com/f2ac64ed7fc467ccdfe3) to get the current beta versions of Chrome to support it. Other than that, only Opera Betas support it at the moment.